# Is "laic" an alternative word to the word "layperson"?

Tags: word-usage, gender-neutral

Can `laic` be used interchangeably with `layperson` as a gender-neutral alternative to `layman` and `laywoman`?

Example 1

> The site is more suitable for the *laics*.

vs

> The site is more suitable for *laypersons*.

Example 2

> *Laics* are not allowed here.

vs

> *Laypersons* are not allowed here.

Example 3

> I am a laic to this subject.

vs

> I am a layperson to this subject.

Comment: Hi Yong Quan: What is it about your question [that can't be answered by a dictionary?](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/laic) We need to know before we can do anything helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not if you want anyone to know what you’re talking about.

[*Laic* is a very rare, formal, ecclesiastic term](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/laic) that virtually no one outside the extremely well educated have ever even heard of, let alone used. *Laic* is to *laity* as *cleric* is *clergy*.  Most people don’t know who the laity even are, not to mention their laic representatives. Almost anyone who does probably knows the original Latin *laicus*, and just how many do you reckon know that word?

*Laic* is one hundred times less frequent than *layman* in [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laic%2Claics%2Clayman%2Claymen%2Claywoman%2Claywomen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Claic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claics%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clayman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claymen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claywoman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claywomen%3B%2Cc0), and the plural *laics* is thrice rarer still.

[image: Google ngram of laic]

If the intent is communication, you should not use these terms outside the exceedingly narrow context of papal bulls and other equivalently religious epistles.

Comment: Tangential at best, but "leek" (pronounced like "lake") in Dutch means "layman/person".